# Why is my object displaying the wrong value?

Tags: python

```
class Box:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self,l,w,d):
        self.width = w
        self.length = l
        self.depth = d
        Box.count+=1

    @staticmethod
    def displayBoxCount():
        print ("Total box created is: %d" %Box.count)

    def calcVolume(self):
        return (self.width*self.length*self.depth)

    def calcSurfaceArea(self):
        return self.width*self.length*2+self.depth*self.width*2+2*self.length*self.depth

    def scale (self,r):
        self.ratio=r
        self.length =self.length*self.ratio
        self.width = self.width*self.ratio
        self.depth =self.depth*self.ratio

        return Box(self.length,self.width,self.depth)

    def add(self,other):
        self.width+=other.width
        self.length+=other.length
        self.depth+=other.depth
        #return Box(self.width + other.width ,self.length +other.length ,self.depth +other.depth)
        return Box(self.width,self.length,self.depth)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Box dimensions (Length,width depth):%0.2f,%0.2f,%0.2f"%(self.length,self.width,self.depth)


b1  = Box(2.0,3.0,2.0)
b2 = Box(3.0,2.0,3.0)
b3=b1.add(b2)
Box.displayBoxCount()
print(b3)
print(b1.calcVolume())
print(b2.calcSurfaceArea())
b2.scale(2.0)
print(b2)
```

This is my code of a simple class named Box.

I want to display object b1's volume using calcVolume method, but it keeps giving me the wrong answer. I got 125 for b1's volume. It is supposed to be b1.
However, when I replace my return expression with the one that I commented, the correct answer is shown.

Aren't they both the same statement and equivalent to each other?

**I have tried using  another alternative, but i'm still getting the incorrect box dimensions for object b2 after having done the scale function, see the second picture**

[image: This is how I want my output to be like]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you call the add method on `b1` in `b1.add(b2)` you add the dimensions of b2 to b1. So the dimensions of `b1` are now the same as those of `b3`. This is why you have the same volume for `b1` as `b3`

Comment: but if i use the uncomment line, it will return the correct answer??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear, but anyway:

```
def add(self,other):
    self.width+=other.width
    self.length+=other.length
    self.depth+=other.depth

    # return Box(self.width + other.width, self.length +other.length ,self.depth +other.depth)
    return Box(self.width,self.length,self.depth)
```

> Aren't they both the same statement and equivalent to each other?

If the only thing that changes between your two versions is which of the "return" statements is used, then no, those are obviously not equivalent. In the first case, you update "self" dimensions once, then return a new box with updated "self" dimensions, in the second case you you update "self" dimensions once, then return a new box with "other" dimensions added a second time.

Note that in both cases, your logic is flawed You want to either leave "self" values alone and return a new box build from "self" and "other" values, **or** update "self" values and not return anything - but from your example snippet I assume you want the first solution, IOW your code should just be:

```
def add(self,other):
    return Box(self.width+other.width ,self.length+other.length ,self.depth +other.depth)
```

Note that you have a similar issue with your `scale` method.

As a side note: you want to avoid hardcoding the class name in you methods, ie here:

```
def __init__(self,l,w,d):
    self.width = w
    self.length = l
    self.depth = d
    Box.count+=1

@staticmethod
def displayBoxCount():
    print ("Total box created is: %d" %Box.count)
```

You want

```
def __init__(self,l,w,d):
    self.width = w
    self.length = l
    self.depth = d
    type(self).count+=1

@classmethod
def displayBoxCount(cls):
    print("Total box created is: %d" % cls.count)
```

Comment: Please check the updated question. I have tried using your method, and I get the ratio wrong this time around... :(

Comment: please stop posting images of code, those are totally unreadable

Comment: and you have to decide whether you want your scale method to change the current instance or to return a new one. It's either one ir the other, not a half-baked mix of both.